# TransactionRequiredException on Delete Query Execution

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jta

I have a strange behaviour happening when executing a delete query. I use spring mvc 3.1 with JPA (hibernate) and oracle DB.
Below is the relevant part of my applicationcontext

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

I have created a custom annotation

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public @interface DefaultServiceTransaction{}
```

which I use on the services to make them transactional.

```
@Service
@DefaultServiceTransaction
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
@Autowired   UserRepositoryuserRepository;
@DefaultServiceTransaction
public void deleteAllForUser(User user){
userRepository.deleteAllForUser(user);
}}
```

The problem is when I execute this service method, I get the exception

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete     query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:321)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.ajc$afterThrowing$org_springframework_orm_jpa_aspectj_JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect$1$18a1ac9(JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.aj:15)
```

The same strategy works for me when I use it for other services (in the same package in fact) - so I don't think the problem has anything to do with the configuration. 
I am clueless....

Comment: Apparently, the problem occurs because of the annotation. If I use @Transactional directly on the method, it works, but if I use the custom annotation, it doesn't. Its strange because this annotation works for me in other services.

Comment: What is the correct usage of the @Transactional annotation? It would be better if you would post your correct solution so others who read this later and learn something from you. Though after 1.5+ years you might not be able too.